# In Powershell how can I use lines in a CSV to search a text file and return multiple lines to another CSV?

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-3.0

Example of what I am trying to do.

I have CSV_A.CSV that contains a list of keywords (each on a new line) like: apple, orange, pear. Note these keywords only occur in the TEXT_FILE exactly 1 time.

I have a text file TEXT_FILE.TXT that has 1000s of lines. I need a script that will search TEXT_FILE for apple, then orange, then pear and return its line as well as the next 5 lines.

So the ending result would be a file that contains 15 lines, 5 for each of the 3 key words.

Currently I have tried the following code and it gives me the first line for each keyword, but nothing more.

```
# path
$path = 'C:\Users\Documents\4_Testing\TEXT_FILE.TXT'


Import-Csv .\CSV_A.csv | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $path | Select-String -Pattern "$($_.KeywordColumn)\(" -Context 0, 5 |
    Select-Object Line |
    add-content -path 'C:\Users\Documents\4_Testing\Output.csv'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change this line:

```
Select-Object Line |
```

to:

```
ForEach-Object { @($_.Line;$_.Context.PostContext) } |
```

This way, each match will produce an array of 6 strings - the matching line, and the five following.

Comment: Wow, you are the best! Thanks!